# Unable to restart networking on Debian with Systemd

Tags: debian, networking

First of all important:

- Debian does **NOT** install **NetworkManager** by default when installed without graphical interface. (I received some answers considering that I did not get how to configure Network Manager)

Well, I am trying to figure out why I just can't restart the networking configuration without a system restart, or doing some ip commands by hand.

For example if i run:

```
systemctl restart networking
```

Does not have any effect.

If I try to:

```
ifdown ensp0
```

It says that the interface is not running....
If i try

```
ifup ensp0
```

Then my interface has 2 ips, instead of one (I just changed it on /etc/network/interfaces)

What I'm doing is using the ip command, to remove the ip by hand, then bringing them all up with ifup. However that is very strange.

So in a way what is the correct form to just restart all the network connections as we do in the ancient versions?

If I add:

```
auto enps0
```

Then networking starts to work better but that is not the default configuration!

Is this more of systemd issue? Or, it is related to the net-tools being deprecated?

Comment: I noticed that Debian 9 installed in graphical mode with Cinnamon, is doing a similar behavior (but in this case in Network Manager), instead of changing the ip the Network Manager GUI is adding a new ip, until system restart.... So you still need to use ip address delete, etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution (workaround) that i found is this :

```
ip address delete theoldip/mask dev enp0s3 
ifdown enp0s3 
ifup enp0s3
```

Or just restart the system after editing /etc/network/interfaces

**Other way (get it on Debian lists):**

First ifdown enp0s3 
then edit /etc/network/interfaces
so only them, you will can do ifup enp0s3, hard to do remotely, you will need a cronjob.

In older versions, you are disconnected when you do service networking restart, then you just can reconnect to it again.

But don't do systemctl restart networking via ssh in new versions it is like to do not get the interface working anymore in any of the ips you have.

Answer (score 2):

Check the name of your interface with.

```
ip a
```

Let's say interface is named enp1s0 do the following to restart networking interface.

```
ifdown enp1s0 && ifup enp1s0
```

It works even via ssh without losing connection.